# how to send grant_type=client_credentials as post request body in Java DSL (Spring boot)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

[image: postman request body]

As seen in the image above, I am sending grant_type=client_credentials as post body. The equivalent curl command is

curl --location --request POST 'https://localhost:8080/token' 
--header 'Authorization: Basic **************************************' 
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'

I am able to send grant_type=client_credentials as query parameter and get a successful response. But we are asked not to use as query param because of company policy and asked to send it in body.

The code which I came up with is

```
public Message<Map<String, String>> getTokenGenRequest() {
        setHeaderMapper(new String[] { TransferConstants.AUTHORIZATION, TransferConstants.CONTENT_TYPE });
        Map<String, String> requestMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        requestMap.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(requestMap)
                .setHeader(TransferConstants.AUTHORIZATION, getAuthCredentials())
                .setHeader(TransferConstants.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).build();
    }


private void setHeaderMapper(String[] headerNames) {
        headerMapper.setOutboundHeaderNames(headerNames);

    }
```

However the request goes out Writing [{grant_type=[client_credentials]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" due to which I am not getting any response.Can somebody tell me what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

The `{grant_type=[client_credentials]}` is a correct `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type.
See HTTP specification: https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#urlencoded-serializing.

You can try to build an `RequestEntity` upfront with the body as a string of that pair, plus add those header manually.

I mean your `getTokenGenRequest()` should return a `Message<HttpEntity<?>>`, but, of course, it would be better to consult with another side (REST service) to be sure what they really want from you. Probably you don't sent some extra header or there is some which they don't accept.

Comment: Thanks @Artem Bilan. I did write a method which generates the token. But i have another problem now. The token generated should be sent as header value to other api. Please note, I have created 2 seperate rest templates , 1 for token and another for api. Can we do that? Also the token generation happens during server startup. But when I send request, the call is going directly to exchange method of rest template without going to token generation code. Also the request is different from what I sent. Can you please tell me where I can be wrong?

Comment: Doesn't sound like related to the original question. Probably better to start a new SO thread with much more info.